# Displaying MapView markers from JSON API

Tags: json, react-native, mkmapview

I am using React Native map view (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) and have successfully got my map to display with manual markers. However, when I try to display my fetched JSON data markers I get constant syntax errors.

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     myMarkers: []
};
  }
componentDidMount() {
   this.getMarkers();
  }

getMarkers() {
    axios
      .get("MYAPISOURCE")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          myMarkers: response.data.responser
        });
      });
  }

render() {
    return (
<MapView style={styles.map}
   rotateEnabled={false}
          initialRegion={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.04,
              longitudeDelta: 0.05,
          }}
        >

   {this.state.myMarkers.map((post, index)=> {
          <MapView.Marker
            key={post.ID}
            coordinate={{
                    latitude:{post.lat},
                    longitude:{post.lng}}}
          />
                 })}


      </MapView>

);
    }
```

My Map View code which keeps getting syntax error: Unexpected tokens, expected "," in the coordinate function. I have tried so many different options but I cannot get the markers and map to work when I have my marker code.

HOWEVER If I run this code below outside of MapView, it successfully displays my data so my API call and myMarkers state is working and has the proper data:

```
    {this.state.myMarkers.map((post, index)=> {

        return (
         <View key={index}>
          <Text>
            {post.lat},
            {post.lat}
          </Text>
         </View>
        )
      })}
```

This displays the following:
37.78825, -122.4324
33.78825, -121.4324
31.78825, -124.4324

Answer (score 0):

The data from the service is coming after the rendering(after the components render with empty values) so you need to use promise with state to render it once its ready.

> examble:-

```
    constructor(){
    super(props);
    this.state={dataIsHere:false};
    }
    dataSource()=>{
    axios.<><><>.then((data)=>this.setState({dataIsHere:true}));
    }
    render(){
    return(
    ...
//It will render markers once the data is ready
    {this.state.dataIsHere?
    this.state.myMarkers.map((post, index)=> {
              <MapView.Marker
                key={post.ID}
                coordinate={{
                        latitude:{post.lat},
                        longitude:{post.lng}}}
              />
                     }):null}
    ...
    )
    }
```